# Matrix Table Variance based on Category Against Fixed Measure

Tags: powerbi, variance, slicers

I have a slicer with multiple selection allowed, where this filter is related with a DAX measure I am trying to calculate in order to find the variance between each selected value volume against highest selected value volume. The values need to be presented in a matrix table.

Assume Slicer Value: P1, P2, P3, P4, P5
Let's say I have selected: P1,P2,P5
With MAXX on SLICER TYPE will have P5 as highest value

---

Database Example

| Type | Volume |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 5000 |
| P2 | 3000 |
| -------- | -------- |
| P3 | 2000 |
| P4 | 1500 |
| -------- | -------- |
| P5 | 1000 |

---

Desired Output in Matrix Table

| Type | Variance |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 4000 |
| P2 | 2000 |
| -------- | -------- |
| P5 | 0 |

---

Variance = DAX measure [Takes the sum of each type in the selection type volume then subtract from highest Selected P]

The challenge I have is that whenever I drop the DAX measure into the variance, the table type category overrides the selected slicer filter in the DAX measure and returns zero. Appreciate your help.